# No errors and no message in codeigniter 4. Data not store in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, model, codeigniter-4

PHP Version
7.3

CodeIgniter4 Version
4.1.5

CodeIgniter4 Installation Method
Composer (using codeigniter4/appstarter)

Which operating systems have you tested for this bug?
Windows

Which server did you use?
apache

Database
MySQL

What happened?
Why is this not working?

1. Data is stored, but does not encrypt the password.

// File: MyEntities()

```
public function setPassword(string $password)
{
         $this->attributes['password'] = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

          return $this;
}
```

// File: MyController.php

```
$model = new MyModel();
$entities = new MyEntities();
$entities->fill($this->request->getPost());
$model->insert($entities)
```

2. There are no error messages and the data is not stored in the database.

// File: MyController.php

```
$model = new MyModel();
$model->insert([
          'field1' => $this->request->getPost('field1'),
          'field2' => $this->request->getPost('field2'),
          'field3' => $this->request->getPost('field3'),
]);
```

I'm stuck and can't find a solution to this problem? And if I look at the documentation what I do is as the documentation describes.

Answer (score 0):

use save function instead insert

```
 if (!$this->model->save(['age'=>'10'])) {
            helper('shared');
            $this->httpException(lang('Shared.api.reject'), ResponseInterface::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,serializeMessages($this->model->errors()));

        }
```